# TensorFlow: Queue visualization mismatch in number in TensorBoard?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am wondering why the names of the scalar summaries for the queue as stated in the left graph of the photo has a number 32.

[image]

Firstly, the reader (a TFRecord reader in this case) has no attribute or whatsoever that causes it to have a number 32. The graph on the right, however, is correct as the RandomShuffleQueue that is created does have a capacity of 256. In my code, I only have 1 reader created. So why is there a `fraction_of_32_full` in my code and what does it mean?

I have always give a different number from what I expected. For instance, when my batch is 8, the FIFO queue for the `tf.train.batch` scalar summary always give me 16. Is that because the queue capacity is always capped at 16?

Comment: Looks like the left one reads training samples from files, the right one randomly shuffle the previously read inputs and feed them to the model. Have you examines the two queue in TensorBoard graph, which might show better picture clarifying what is happening.